# Trouble with While Loop in Python

Tags: python-2.7

I wanted to create a game called "Guess The Number".

I wanted the program to generate a random number and compare it with the value the user entered, and write the number of times it was correct/wrong into a text file.

The first part of the program works fine, and the problem comes at the end, where I'm asking for the user's input to decide whether to quit/continue with the program.

It keeps on asking for the user's input on whether to quit/continue.

Ex :-

> Welcome to the Guess the Number game!
>
> Enter a number between 1 to 10 : 4
>
> You guess the number incorrectly!
>
> Press Q to quit or E to continue : E
>
> Press Q to quit or E to continue : Q
>
> Press Q to quit or E to continue : E

Doesn't quit or continue the program, below is my code, please help me out. Just a beginner in Python, self learning.

```
 import random


print "Welcome to the Guess the Number game!"
print

c = True
lost = 0
win = 0
j = ""
d = True

while c == True:
    v = random.randint(1,10)
    n = input("Enter a number between 1 to 10 : ")
    print
    if n > 10:
        print "The number you entered is above 10, please enter a number below 10."
        print
    elif n < 0:
        print "The number you entered is below 0, please enter a number above 0."
        print
    elif 0<n<10:
        print "Progressing..."
        print
    else:
        j = " "
    if n == v:
        print "Congratulations, you guess the number correctly!"
        print
        win = win + 1
        file = open("text.txt","w") 
        file.write("Number of times won : %s \n" %(win))
        file.close()
    else:
        print "You guess the number incorrectly!"
        print        
        lost = lost + 1
        file = open("text.txt","w") 
        file.write("Number of times lost : %s \n" %(lost))
        file.close()      
    while d == True:
        response =  raw_input("Press Q to quit or E to continue : ")
        response = str(response)          
        print        
        if response == 'Q':
            c = False
            d == False
        elif response == 'E':
            c = True
            d == False
        else:
            print("Please read the instructions properly and press the proper button.")
            print        
            d == True
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in this while loop

```
while d == True:
    response =  raw_input("Press Q to quit or E to continue : ")
    response = str(response)          
    print        
    if response == 'Q':
        c = False
        d == False
    elif response == 'E':
        c = True
        d == False
    else:
        print("Please read the instructions properly and press the proper button.")
        print        
        d == True
```

there is a big difference between = (an assignment operator) and == (a comparison operator) the first one (=) will rewrite what the variable is and store the new value in memory. ==, however will only compare what is on the left to what is on the right, so essential when you put d == False or True, you are never reassigning the variable and it will stay within that loop forever. To correct it you just need to change it to this

```
while d == True:
    response =  raw_input("Press Q to quit or E to continue : ")
    response = str(response)          
    print        
    if response == 'Q':
        c = False
        d = False
    elif response == 'E':
        c = True
        d = False
    else:
        print("Please read the instructions properly and press the proper button.")
        print        
        d = True
```

Comment: Oh my god, thanks! My bad, I just copied and pasted the "d == false" part!